# Javascript not-well formed error in for loop

Tags: javascript, debugging

I copied this code from an [example](http://www.lazycoder.com/weblog/2009/08/12/a-simple-map-function-for-plain-javascript-arrays/). I've read it 100 times.

```
Array.prototype.map = function(fn) {
    var r = [];
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        r.push(fn(this[i]));
    }
    return r;
};
```

Why does Firefox say:

```
not well-formed
file:///some/path.html                         Line: 5
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    -------------------^
```

**UPDATE**

The error is only shown when Firebug is turned on for the page.

Comment: Works fine - http://jsbin.com/ifuhu/edit

Comment: Your problem got solved, but I would encourage you to check if there is a native `map` implementation before declaring your own (which will shadow the native one if were available), the native implementations provided by moderns browsers are *really* much more faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using Javascript code in an HTML page claiming to be fully XHTML-compliant.  Therefore, the `<` character cannot appear in the Javascript, as it would be interpreted as the beginning of an XHTML tag.

There are a number of ways to fix this.

You could change the `DOCTYPE` and make it not XHTML.
You could enclose the Javascript in a `<![CDATA[` section.
You could move the Javascript into a separate .js file.
You could escape every occurrence of `<` with `&lt` and every `&` with `&amp;`.  I do not recommend this option; it'll make your code unreadable and will almost definitely not work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your error isn't in this code, but something above it trickling errors down.  So, instead of finding an error in this code, look above for malformed HTML or javascript that could be causing this error instead.

Comment: There is no HTML or other Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  Please post the full file, and make sure you are using script tags.

I posted a [validating pastebin file](http://jsbin.com/irafi) (Chetan's was technically not valid), and it works fine with Firebug.  So I suggest you come back with a full page of validating code that doesn't work.

Comment: That IS the full file, aside from various combinations of html and script tags. I've tried with just a script tag. I've tried with a full HTML page including just a script tag in the body, with and without a doctype.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the following HTML and your text as "test.js", I too get no errors in Firebug.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
</html>
```